# How to install FTDI Serial Drivers on Mac?

Tags: serial, arduino-ide, usb, ftdi

[I'm following this tutorial on how to install FTDI drivers on macOS](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ftdi-drivers/all#mac), but am facing some issues. After downloading the USB Serial Driver version 2.4.4 (for OS X 10.14) from [FTDI Chip's virtual COM port (VCP) driver page](https://ftdichip.com/drivers/vcp-drivers/) (recommended by the tutorial), I still don't see any `usbserial` option listed under the Serial Port tab, shown below.

[image: Missing USB Serial Port]

Because I'm running macOS Monterrey (12.0.1), I also tried downloading the Beta driver release (version 1.5.0) for OS X 10.15 and macOS 11/12. After running the installer from my Applications folder (as recommended), I get the following result, indicating success, but the options list remains the same as shown above.

[image: Successful Installation]

Are there any workarounds? For reference, I am using Arduino IDE 2.0.0.

Answer (score 2):

I have just managed to get the FTDI set up for my M1 mac using the Pro Mini. I think the issue is that newer macs automatically block the FTDI serial connection from being used as a com port. You need to install a program called **D2XXHelper** to prevent this behaviour.

I did the following, hopefully this will work for you too:

1. Install **FTDI VCP Driver**, found [here](https://ftdichip.com/drivers/vcp-drivers/): Scroll down to first table and find the latest Mac OS drivers. There are 2, the 2.4.4 version and the 1.5 version. I think you need to use the 1.5 version for the M1 but I’m not sure because I installed both before I did the next steps to get it working.
2. Install the **D2XXHelper** found [here](https://ftdichip.com/drivers/d2xx-drivers/): Scroll down to first table and look in the comments column for the Mac OS row to find the download link.
3. After installing the D2XXHelper, you should get a security prompt saying **system extension blocked**. Follow [this](https://support.techsmith.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056384711-M1-M2-Chip-and-the-Snagit-System-Audio-Capture-Component#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20system%20extensions%2C%20you,from%20the%20Security%20Policy%20button.) guide which shows how to provide permission for the system extension to be applied – this requires going into recovery mode and requires several computer restarts.
4. After following the steps in the guide, you should have enabled the D2XXHelper system extensions to be applied, in which case when you connect your Arduino to your computer via the FTDI connector, the Arduino IDE 2 should now recognise that a device has been connected via the FTDI virtual com port.
5. **optional** – to check that your FTDI is connected correctly to your Arduino, connect it up, Open a Terminal window and type “ls /dev/tty.*” and run this command. If the FTDI is connected properly then a usb serial device should show up in the results to this command.